# Using setters and getter variables on HTML (angular component)

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a simple angular component to test the usage of a variable that uses a getter/setter style:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  _name = 'Variable Example';
  get name(): string {
    console.log("GET!!!");
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(value:string): void {
    this._name = value;
  }
}
```

Then, I use this variable on the html:

```
<p>
  {{ name }}
</p>
```

What I noticed is that the `get name()` is called 4 times (check live in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8conqj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html))

There is any best practices rules which points out that `getter` and `setters` shouldn't be used on html components? Will I have performance issues using this approach?

Thank you!

PS: This is not the real scenario, it just a small example of what I'm doing.

Comment: What is the value of the getter and setter in this case? Just use the property directly, you can always refactor later if you actually *need* some logic on get or set.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is just an example. For my real case I have some logic on the setter and getter.

Comment: Your exemple run in dev mode, so Angular run the change detector twice to check for "Expression has changed after it was checked" kind of error. In prod mode, you'll see only 2 "GET !!!". But I don't know why Angular needs 2 calls :/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here are my rule of thumbs that served me very well:

1. **Always use `OnPush`** change detection strategy to avoid unnecessary checks
2. **Always use immutable data**, update entire array/object on any change. Google immutability if you are not familiar with it, it is very helpful and a must for `OnPush`.
3. **Never store states that can be calculated**. If it can be computed using say component @Inputs - go for a **getter**. Computing a simple getter with math or going through a small array is very fast and it saves you the trouble of syncing states. I did benchmarking in Firefox, a simple getter going over a 100 elements array executes 7 million times per second. Generally, getters will not be bottle necks of your app and they are much easier to work with, instead of updating states in lifecycle hooks. But read further.
4. If your computed state produces a new **array** or **object** - always use **pure pipe** to avoid unnecessary recalculation as it is a much heavier operation and is not suitable for getter.
5. If your getter is not going to change - consider **lazy initialization** pattern:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Smart_self-overwriting_lazy_getters
6. **Avoid ngOnChange** in favor of setters on @Inputs - this way your changes propagate more "directly". Something changed - related stuff is updated, instead of "side effecting" it to some hook to be called later.

**NOTICE:** These are just my thought on the matter that I've developed over a couple of years of working with Angular on complex projects.

You can read more on declarative approach in writing Angular code in this article I wrote:
https://indepth.dev/compliant-components-declarative-approach-in-angular/

Answer (score 10):

You should avoid calling methods/getter from your template because the method will be called every time change detection runs.

Instead you should compute whatever you want inside something like ngOnInit and assign it to a variable or use a pipe.

If you want to compute every time your value changes, you should use a pipe since it would be called only when input values change and not every time the change detection runs.